# How to connect Flex application with Java

Tags: apache-flex, jakarta-ee, flex4, adobe, blazeds

I have a average Java knowledge. but i don't have a good knowledge about adobe flex. i want to create flex application which will work with java and i see through the internet it can be done by using BlazeDS. there is 2 configuration files called services-config.xml and remoting-config.xml. I don't have any idea about these files. if these are automatically created through the flex or will i have to create these files manually ? and how to connect flex application with java web project.

I followed this - http://cgrant.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/connecting-flex-to-java-with-blazeds/

Please help me.

Comment: You need to read the doco.
 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/livecycle/articles/blazeds_gettingstarted.html

http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=splash.html

Comment: Those files should be included as part of BlazeDS.

Comment: @ keyle n @ Reboog711 - I found it. Thank you.........

Answer (score 0):

There are several middlewares meet your requirement.

In addition, another 2 are:

- [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/) (recommended, much powerful than BlazeDS)
- [Pimento](http://www.spicefactory.org/pimento/docs/1.1/manual/) (Support enum type)